# detecting and removing single line comments in code in Java

Tags: java, compiler-construction

So I am making this compiler which compiles a text file into machine code for an OS to read from an SD card. code will look something like this: (Ra text_to_store) which stores text in to string slot a. most of it seems to be doable with

```
mystring=mystring.replace("String ","R");
mystring=mystring.replace("=","");
mystring=mystring.replace(";","");
//cannot replace " with nothing, how do I get around this?
```

as this turns String a=text_t_ store; into the correct code.

but of course not all can be done with this. for example, I need to get rid of comments (//commented stuff) which is not doable with .replace, along with a few other things. this is probably something simple, but I cannot find it!

p.s. can you also provide a link/help with text formatting? for example int var; needs to be turned into a number for the slot of RAM. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use mystring.replaceAll which uses a regular expression, such as

```
mystring = mystring.replaceAll("//.*$","");
```

replacing from the // to the end of the line with nothing

Comment: Probably worth adding a note that this might screw up the code.  e.g. a source line like `String url = "http://example.com/...";`  (in other words, naive string replacement only gets you so far, at some point you need a proper lexer...)

Comment: This is true, it would screw that up. Maybe a check to see if it was at the front of the line or not. I assume this is theoretical, as you would never want to make a compiler with string.replace anyway

Comment: I will not be using URLs, but it works! thanks! now to figure out how to do vars...

Answer (score 0):

you can have it all in 1 line with replaceAll and a regex

```
mystring=mystring.replaceAll("(?:.|\\s)*String ([\\w]+)=(.*?);(?:.|\\s)*","R$1 $2");
```

Comment: 4 illegal escape characters according to netbeans, but it runs. however, it has no effect on text at all.

Comment: hmm... still no affect on text.

Comment: you got multiple lines in your mystring, think i fixed it

Comment: still nothing. code:
{
static String stuff="String stuff=string-ness;\n//I am a comment";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String mystring=stuff.replaceAll("String ([\\w]+)=([\\w\\s]+);[ ]*(?://[\\d\\D]*)?","R$1 $2");
        System.out.println(mystring);
    }
}
}

Comment: your string has a '-' in it and the regex i wrote only looked for letters and spaces since thats what you had as an example, added support for anything now

Comment: ahh forget it. it is giving me errors about meta character '?'

Comment: my bad, left a bit to much in when i did the edit, updated it